# Rotating the plot label with achartengine in android doesn't work

Tags: android, achartengine

am a newbie to android. How do I rotate the plot label? am able to rotate the label in the axis though. am using achartengine. can someone please help?

```
public class SimpleChartExample extends Activity {

    private GraphicalView mChartView;

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layoutlinechart);

        ...
        ...


        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE,Color.RED};
        PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE,PointStyle.CIRCLE};

        renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);


        renderer.setXLabels(12);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        renderer.setShowGrid(false);
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        ...
     }
  }
```

As seen in the code snippet above, am able to configure the chart X, Y Axis etc, Am also able to plot the values. But how do I set a rotation angle for the plot values?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to rotate.

Comment: Hi Dan, I want to rotate the plot label. i.e. the value shown next to each plot point i.e. circle.

Comment: There is not API for that currently.